# Translating url regular expressions into path in django 2.1

Tags: python, django, django-urls

```
url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        views.activate, name='activate'),
```

I've been doing tutorial but in django 2.1 you have to use path, how do I translate to 2.1 django compatibile path function?

Does the

```
path('activate/<str:uidb64>/<uuid:token>/', views.activate, name='activate')
```

do the same?

Comment: No you do not have to use `path`, but it is advisable to use `re_path`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I've been doing tutorial but in django 2.1 you have to use path, how do I translate to 2.1 django compatibile path function?

**No**, in [django-2.x](/questions/tagged/django-2.x), you can use [**`path`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#path) or [**`re_path`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path). Furthermore as of today, [**`url`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#url) is still supported, but will likely dissapear in the future.

`re_path` is in fact equivalent to the old `url`, so you can write this as:

```
re_path(
    r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    views.activate,
    name='activate'
),
```

It is not easy to construct a completely equivalent URL, since Django only supports [five path conversions by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#path-converters):

> Path converters
>
> The following path converters are available by default:
>
> 1. `str` - Matches any non-empty string, excluding the `path` separator, `'/'`. This is the default if a converter isn't included in the expression.
> 2. `int` - Matches zero or any positive integer. Returns an `int`.
> 3. `slug` - Matches any `slug` string consisting of ASCII letters or numbers, plus the hyphen and underscore characters. For example,
>      building-your-1st-django-site.
> 4. `uuid` - Matches a formatted `UUID`. To prevent multiple URLs from mapping to the same page, dashes must be included and letters must be
>      lowercase. For example, 075194d3-6885-417e-a8a8-6c931e272f00. Returns
>      a `UUID` instance.
> 5. `path` - Matches any non-empty string, including the `path` separator, '/'. This allows you to match against a complete URL
>      `path` rather than just a segment of a URL `path` as with `str`.

We can use `slug` here, but this will match *more* than the given URL:

```
path(
    r'^activate/(<slug:uidb64>/<slug:token>/$',
    views.activate,
    name='activate'
),
```

The [`slug` pattern takes as regex equivalent](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/urls/converters.py#L36):

> ```
> class SlugConverter(StringConverter):
>     regex = '[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+'
> ```

Comment: Great answer, that's what I've been looking for - thanks.